# Cannot create more than 2 circles on GUI

Tags: java, user-interface

I'm learning to work with GUI and I'm trying to draw multiple ovals. But in the example below I cannot draw more than 2 ovals for some reason.

**frame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel);** draws the 1st oval

**frame.add(new DrawPanel());** draws the 2nd oval

and another **frame.add(new DrawPanel());** does not draw anything. Why?

```
package Package1;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Gui {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Gui gui = new Gui();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    DrawPanel drawPanel = new DrawPanel();

    frame.getContentPane().add(drawPanel); // This creates the 1st circle
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(new DrawPanel()); // This creates the 2nd circle
    frame.add(new DrawPanel()); // This doesn't create anything
   }
}
```

```
package Package1;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    int x = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
    int y = (int) (Math.random() * 100);

    g.setColor(Color.RED);
    g.drawOval(x, y, 150, 150);
}
```

}

Comment: Why aren't you just overriding the paint method off one panel for this?

Answer (score 1):

`JFrame`s have a `BorderLayout`. By default, when a component is added to one, it goes in the center of the frame. When another one is added, it goes in the center as well, overriding the old one. To fix this, you can use a different layout (`FlowLayout` might be what you are looking for) or use a different part of the border layout (like `PAGE_END` or `LINE_START`).